# WCF RIA Services Validation: Validate that Field is Unique Without Making it a Key

Tags: c#, wcf, validation, ria

The title is somewhat self explanatory.  I have an entity that has another key already defined (that must remain that way) and I need to validate that a certain field is unique.

I am hoping to use a `Validator` applied in the metadata.   But I can't use `DomainService` there since the code must run on both Server and Client.  So I have no idea how I could access my entity set to see if the field's value is unique....

Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Unique without unique? How is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to create a file with the extension `.shared.cs` on the Server side.  Put the validator in that:

```
public class CustomValidation
{
     public static ValidationResult ValidateUnique(object o, ValidationContext c)
     {
         #if SILVERLIGHT
             //Do actual validation client-side:
             MyObject mo = c.ObjectInstance as mo; //Object we are checking is type MyObject
             MyDS ctx = new MyDS; //Domain Service
             System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.InvokeOperation<bool> 
                    isUnique = //some invoke operation in Domain Service;

             isUnique .Completed += (s, e) =>
             {
                 if (!isUnique .HasError && !isUnique.Value)
                 {
                      //return error;
                      mo.ValidationErrors.Add(error);
                 }
             };
         #endif
         //Server-side always returns success:
         return ValidationResult.Success;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

U can Do that like this

> string _Str = string.Empty;
>           public string Str
>           {
>               get { return _Str; }
>
> set
>      {
>         if ()// add ur code here to check whether it is unique or not
>           {
>
> ```
>         throw new Exception("Please Enter EmailId");
>     }
>   _Str = value; OnPropertyChanged("Str");
>
>     }
> ```

This will be the declaration of ur property and u can make it unique